# Choosing multiplexer to convert current to different voltage

Tags: multiplexer

I want to convert 0-20mA current to 0-1V , 0-5V , 0-10V with different resistors using a multiplexer, but the problem is that my output voltage is not correct and off more than 1V.

I know that different multiplexer have different Ro and current leakage(which is the most important), but how can I calculate this error and what else do I have to for look in datasheet to choose a correct multiplexer, or if you know a part number that can work for this purpose.

The goal is to convert 20mA X 500ohm = 10V, or 20mA x 250ohm = 5V

[image]

Comment: not a good starting point, anyway what's the purpose of this? 0..20mA shall be transformed to suitable adc range, which is unique.

Comment: My circuit generate 0-20mA , but some customer are looking for 0-10V which in this industries they just put a parallel resistor  which convert it to 0-10V, what I want do to be able to this from micro controller using a multiplexer

Comment: So you want an embedded system (your circuit) that can output 0..20mA, 0..10V, 0..1V, 0..5V?

Comment: Exactly, I am already outputting 0-20mA , but I am stock on 0-1,0-5,0-10V output put, since I want use multiplexer to change output to voltage.

Comment: You can't do it with multiplexer, further the current output and voltage output are usually separated in PLC system. You can use XTR300 and dip switches to set output voltage range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was reconsidering your problem: you have 2 input signals and you want to use a multiplexer to connect each signal to 1 of 4 outputs (being current output or one of the voltage outputs  0-1V , 0-5V , 0-10V).

**Regarding the leakage current:**
According the datasheet of the [MC74HC4052](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MC74HC4051-D.PDF),

- the Maximum **Off**–Channel Leakage Current (\$I_{off}\$) is max 1.0 uA at 125­°C
- the Maximum **On**-Channel Leakage Current (\$I_{on}\$) is max 4.0 uA at 125­°C

So, selecting 1 output (and so, the other 3 outputs are off) yields a total leakage of \$1 \cdot I_{on} + 3 \cdot I_{on} = 7.0 \text{ uA}\$ at 125­°C.

**That leakage current definitely will not cause the error of 1V you describe**, because 500 Ω * 7 uA = **3.5 mV.** at most at 125­°C.

**Regarding the Ro of the multiplexer:**
One of the main adventages using a 4–20 mA current loop is that the signal is **independent** of the resistance in the loop<sup>(1)</sup>.
So, this **Ro of the multiplexer is completely irrelevant**. The current through the sense resistors (50, 250 or 500 ohm) will be dictated by the sensor/transducer that acts as current source, and the voltage drop across the sense resistor will be this dictated current times the value of the sense resistor.

**Reasons for measurement errors:**

> [the] output voltage is not correct and off more than 1V

In case of the 500 ohm resistor, this means an error of 1 V / 500 Ω = 2 mA.

Some reasons for the measurement error I can think of:

- ground loops / earth loops (most likely)
- inaccuracy of the input current (the sensor / transducer input signal)
- crosstalk / induced currents due to magnetic fields (less likely with 2 mA)

---

<sup>(1)</sup> In the ideal case. In reality, there is a limit (in voltage / power) for the sensor/transducer to succeed acting as current source.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a complete different approach: use a programmable gain aplifier (PGA) using the following circuit:

[image]

The above edited picture is from the "PGA11x Zerø-Drift Programmable Gain Amplifier With Mux" datasheet. However, this PGA11x series cannot output 10V.

You need to search for a PGA having these **scope gains** with a higher supply voltage rating (as you can search on that parameter and most PGA's can output close to rail-to-rail).

Comment: That is a good idea but this will convert the 0-20mA to voltage but I want to have option to provide 0-20mA,0-1V, 0-5V,0-10V to customer base on their needs.